# Do cross-browser web CSS rounded border generators exist?

Tags: css

I am aware of CSS gradient generators such as Color Zilla

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Do CSS rounded corner generators exist that work across many browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This one](http://css3generator.com/) has worked really well for me.

Comment: Wow, this site rocks. I am never using graphics for gradients, text shadows, rounded corners, or the like again :D :D :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) to replicate CSS3 support in Internet Explorer (versions 6-9)

As stated on their [site](http://css3pie.com/about/):

> PIE currently adds full or partial support to IE 6 through 8 for the following CSS3 features:
>
> - border-radius
> - box-shadow
> - border-image
> - multiple background images
> - linear-gradient as background image
>
> In addition, PIE adds support for border-image and linear-gradient to
>   IE 9, which already supports the other features natively.

Answer (score -3):

you can try this

```
.rounded-corners {
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```